# Find out number from pondering percentages

Tags: percentages

**Update**

*To sumarize:*

Given a,b,c,d ∈ [0,100]
and 0.4a+0.3b+0.2c+0.1d=74

How can I find a,b,c,d ?

**Old**

First question here, and may ( or not ) be simple but I just can't see it.

To explain myself, let me introduce this situation:

- I have 4 numbers from 0 to 100:
  a=100
  b=80
  c=20
  d=60
- Those result in another number using pondering percentages where
  40% is a,
  30% is b,
  20% is c
  and 10% is d

So, given that
40%a + 30%b + 20%c + 10%d
= 74

But what I want to know is how can I find a, b, c & d out of 74 ( knowing the percentages )

Thanks

Comment: You need to rephrase the entire question to something like: Given $a,b,c,d\in[0,100]$ and $0.4a+0.3b+0.2c+0.1d=74$, how can we find $a,b,c,d$? I'm pretty sure that there are infinitely many solutions (unless $a,b,c,d$ are integers).

Comment: Oh thanks. My algebra is very basic, gonna edit the question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough information to uniquely determine $a,b,c$ and $d$ simply from the equation

$$ 0.4a + 0.3b +0.2c + 0.1d = 74$$

In fact, there are an infinite number of real valued solutions to this equation. Restricting $a,b,c,d \in [0,100]$ removes many possible solutions, but it still not enough. To see this, pick one of the variables and isolate it on the left hand side. I will choose to solve for $a$, but I just as easily could have picked any of the others. Doing this gives:

$$ a = \frac{74-0.3b-0.2c-0.1d}{0.4}=185 - \frac{3}{4}b - \frac{1}{2}c - \frac{1}{4}d$$

Now we have an expression for $a$. But we also want $0 \leq a\leq100$. Substituting the expression we found for $a$, into this inequality gives:

$$ 0\leq 185 - \frac{3}{4}b - \frac{1}{2}c - \frac{1}{4}d\leq100 $$

We can clean this up a little bit by multiplying by $4$, subtracting the constant term, and then multiplying by $-1$:

$$ 0\leq740-3b-2c-d\leq400$$
$$ -740\leq-3b-2c-d\leq-340$$
$$ 340\leq 3b+2c+d\leq740$$

So, any $b,c,d \in [0,100]$ that satisfies this inequality will work for us. Then, once we have $b,c,$ and $d$, we can plug them back into our expression for $a$ and we will have a solution.

It's not hard to find $b,c,$ and $d$ to satisfy the inequality. For example $b=80,c=80,d=80$ works. Plugging these back into the first expression gives $a=65$. Here we have a set of numbers that solve the original problem you posed. It's not hard to see that there are an infinite amount of numbers that will work. Just imagine changing $b,c,$ and $d$ a little bit. If the change is small enough, they will still satisfy the inequality, and you will get another $a$ that works using these new values in the original expression.

Comment: Yeah.. I understand how infinite it is. But if you don't mind me asking, could be it be possble given the LCD of a, b, c, d ?

Comment: @marsh LCD (least common denominator) doesn't make sense to ask unless you are considering a,b,c,d as fractions. Do you mean gcd or lcm?

Comment: I did mean LCM just checked it :/ sorry

Comment: @marsh Specifying LCM means that you are also saying you only want $a,b,c$ and $d$ to be integers (since LCM of a non integer value doesn't make sense). Simply requiring integer solutions like this will ensure that you get a finite number of solutions. If you specify the LCM you will further limit the number of solutions. The amount of solutions is dependent on what you specify LCM to be. For instance, if you specify that you want the LCM to be $2$ then it's fairly easy to see there will be _no_ solutions. Answering your question when specifying any LCM in general is a more difficult problem.